# When is it a free kick inside the penalty area?

Tags: rules, football, penalty-shot

I have seen many instances were athletes have taken a free-kick inside the penalty area. Its like a usual free-kick with the wall trying to block the shot however taken inside the penalty area. In what situation does a referee decide to give this decision?

Comment: Hi Utsav. Free kicks are only taken in the penalty area if they are *indirect* free kicks - otherwise, a penalty kick is taken instead. Answers to the linked question list these offences.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this question as it's not an exact duplicate. This question asks how an attacking free kick can be taken in the penalty area. The other one asks for which offences an indirect free kick is awarded.

Comment: @studro Can I use your comment in my post so it clears it up for everyone?

Comment: Well, it'd be much better if the question was re-opened - then you can post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. I've cast a re-open vote. Here's hoping that other users also vote to re-open.